# Problem with system of equations (a;b;c)

Tags: systems-of-equations

I wonder how to solve this system of equations:

\begin{cases}a = \left(b-c\right)^{2}\\b = \left(a-c\right)^{2}\\c = \left(a-b\right)^{2}\end{cases}

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What attempts have you done so far?

Comment: I am assuming that you mean besides the trivial one of $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: The easy ones are $(0,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)$

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ required to be integers?

Answer (score 1):

We have $$a - b = (b-c)^2 - (a-c)^2 = (b -c -a+c)(b-c+a - c) = (b-a)(b+a - 2c)$$ Assuming $a \not = b$, $$1 = -(b+a - 2c) = -b-a+2c \implies c = \frac{1+a+b}{2}$$Plugging in the last equation, $$\frac{1+a+b}{2} = (a-b)^2$$ Note that $a,b\ge 0$. Solving this quadratic equation when $a \ge -\frac{9}{16}$, $$b = \frac{4a - \sqrt{16a + 9} + 1}{4}, b = \frac{4a + \sqrt{16a + 9} + 1}{4}$$ Now use these solutions and the first equation to find $a = 0,b=1$ or $a = 1,b = 0$. If $a = b$ then $c = 0$ and $$a = b^2 \\ b = a^2 $$ which implies $a = b = 1$ or $a = b = 0$.

Comment: If $a=b=2$ and $c=0$ then $a\not = (b-c)^2$.  Instead if $a=b$ then $c=0$ and $a=b^2=a^2$ so $a=0$ or $1$.

Comment: @Henry Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: You are an old user, so I want to just remind you that it is **not** the ideal practice to post answers to without-context questions.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 You're right. I tried to leave most of calculations(which is solving the quadratic equation) to OP.

Comment: You have also not fully solved the $a\not=b$ case: there are only two possible values of $(a,b)$ in that case

Comment: @Henry Thanks. I think it's fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for help. However, I am still not sure how you get "b". Could you please explain it a little more in depth.

Comment: @user10203585 Expand $\frac{1+a+b}{2} = (a-b)^2$ and use [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) to solve for $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for a possible approach:

- Substitute  $a=(b-c)^2$ into $b=(a-c)^2$
- Expand this into an quartic equation involving $b$ and $c$
- That can be factorised into two quadratics involving $b$ and $c$
- So you can get four possible expressions for $b$ in terms of $c$
- You can then use each of these in $c=(a-b)^2$ to get corresponding values of $c$ (messy but simplifies nicely), and thus working backwards of $b$ and $a$
- so you end with a set of solutions for $(a,b,c)$